# Images return status 200 yet are not showing after URL rewriting with .htaccess

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

## Situation

I have two domains: *alfa.nl* and *beta.nl*. Both use the same server. The web content of *beta.nl* is located in `folderB` of *alfa.nl*. I have created an `.htaccess` file in the root of the *alfa.nl* server that rewrites URLs from *beta.nl* to load the web content from `folderB`. The `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?beta\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^folderB/ /folderB%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This all works fine.

## Problem

When I open *beta.nl*, no images are shown. The CSS file refers to some images, but they are not shown. When I look at the network traffic, I see the GET call to retrieve one of the images and the server responds with a 200 OK status code. Yet the preview tab says: "Failed to load response data" and the site does not show the image.

## Attempts to solve

What I've tried to solve:

- Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
- Add `<base href="/">`
- Use relative path to image file (`media/image.png`)
- Use absolute path to image file (`/folderB/media/image.png`)
- Use full path to image file (`http://alfa.nl/folderB/media/image.png`)
- Use full path to image file (`http://beta.nl/media/image.png`)

The first attempt breaks the URL rewriting (shows web content of *alfa.nl* instead of *beta.nl*). All other attempts change nothing: 200 OK status code, no images.

Comment: Did you try to clear your cache or with other browser ?

Comment: Can you goto the full path to the image? Meaning if you put the full path in to the address bar, does it show?